# How to implement methods inside view.onClickListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hi I added in some checks for my application to check if the server is up or not. So i put in a method into a `view.OnclickListener` and i got some error. 
I got this error

> The method serverRespond() is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}

So i want to ask how can i solve this issue?

EDIT
My bad for not inputting my code
Here is my code:

```
// save button click event
    btnSaveEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if ( serverRespond() == true) {
```

and i get the error from the above. Its a java syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You likely need to reference the outer class that your `OnClickListener` is defined in. For example, suppose your Activity is called `MyActivity`. Then, invoke your method like this:

```
MyActivity.this.serverRespond();
```

Comment: My bad. I need to use that method to check for e.g. if(serverRespond() == true){

Comment: You'll need to update your question with more specifics then, like the exact error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a method inside of another method in Java. You can implement the method in the parent class and reference it in the onClick.

Answer (score 0):

OnClickListener is an interface, you can't add methods to it.

usually when create an Activity that implements this interface and pass itself to a view, like this:

```
public class MyActivity implements View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onCreate() {
        // ...
        View view = findViewById(R.id.my_view_id);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        //
    }

    public void onClick() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Of course that's only one way of doing it...
When we have to many callbacks is a good practice to create classes that are specifically listeners, so the activity code is not too big.

Comment: but i need the method to be inside because i need to check for server respond. what else can i do?

Comment: You can put methods in the class that implements the interface. In my example would be MyActivity. Isn't that enough?